# Common data in the fillable fields not passing from pdf to pdf when merged using org.apache.pdfbox-2.0.6

Tags: java, pdf, merge, pdfbox

We are using PDFMergerUtility method `mergeDocuments(org.apache.pdfbox.io.MemoryUsageSetting)` to merge two fillable pdf files. The pdfs get merged but passing the common data(data for fields like `name`, `age` which are present in more than 2 pages of the pdfs) from pdf to pdf is not getting copied.
Say for instance we have a 2 pdfs and both the pdfs contains `name` and `date of birth` fillable fields. When we merge these 2 pdfs using the aforementioned method the values in the fields does not get copied from pdf to pdf.

```
PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
merger.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getByteArray()));
merger.setDestinationStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
merger.`mergeDocuments`(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(2000000));
```

Comment: Why are you using 2.0.6 and not the current version? And can you share the two PDF files?

Comment: I am unable to add the pdfs to the post can you help me how do we do that?

Comment: upload them to a sharehoster e.g. dropbox, Google drive etc

Comment: is it that some documents contain the data for 'name' etc and there the fields value shows up bit fields from other documents are not populated with the data? If yes, this is intented at the  moment. PDFBox treats fields with the same name from different documents as different fields and renames them internally. PDFBOX-3111 ist about to change that.

Comment: Thanks @Maruan Sahyoun. By when are we anticipating these changes to be built in? If they are already done which version has those changes?

Comment: If the version is not available real soon, Is there any other way of merging pdfs other than using itext and Apache pdfbox?

Comment: I just saw new version and release note for version 2.0.9 for apache pdfbox it talks about merging pdf forms. I tried this version but it is still giving the same results of not enabling the fillable fields. Can you please let me know if any solution is available? Thanks in advance!

Comment: after few years, this was yet not closed. I tested it in the latest 2 (2.0.24) and the forms (and their values/functionalities) are retained in the merged output.